# Is there a way to get the value of {{org}} from this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, function

```
<html>  
    <input type="text" ng-model="selectedOrg" ng-show="!isSuperAdmin" readonly />  
    <select id="nameOrg" ng-model="selectedOrg" ng-change="changeOrg()" ng-disabled="!isSuperAdmin" ng-show="isSuperAdmin">  
        <option ng-repeat="org in orglist">{{org}}</option>  
    </select>  
    <script>  
        var value = $(nameOrg).val()  
    </script>  
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see **[ask]** and **[mcve]**.

Comment: This should be tagged with jQuery, assuming that's what the dollar sign means...Why did you undo that edit?

Comment: No one can see your code now. Can you at least fix it yourself by [edit]ing your question? (The link is on your post but the one in my comment will also let you edit it.)

Comment: To edit the code, select the code and hit CTRL + K. For more, see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the quotes, `nameOrg` is an invalid JavaScript variable.

```
    $(nameOrg)
```

Here's the right way to select an element by it's ID:

```
    $('#nameOrg')
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Also, I see your html document does not contain any reference of jQuery. Make sure you are importing the library.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I strongly suggest wrapping the code in a [jQuery ready function](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) as well, otherwise `$` will not be available at runtime.

After you have done all the above, refer to the linked duplicate question on how to get the selected text. What `.val()` does is to get the selected option's value (`<option value="text"></option>`), not the text between the option tag (`<option>text</option>`).

Comment: Yes, upon adding the "text" as a value i get to assign it to a variable, but not the ones within <option>text</option>